# Alternative methodology instead of NOT IN

Tags: database

**Employee Table**

```
EmployeeId 

E001         
E002         
E003         
E004
```

**Service Table**

```
ServiceDate     EmployeeId

4/07/2014       E001
3/07/2014       E002
3/01/2014       E004
```

I want to list the details of employee(s) who has/have never done any car service.

The result should be:

```
EmployeeId
E003
```

I tried outer join `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but it got messed up.

Comment: You should not use outer join. Just join or use where not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of using `NOT IN`, like so:

```
select e.* 
from employee e
left join service s on e.employeeid = s.employeeid
where s.employeeid is null
```

The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that you get a result set where every employee may or may not have a matching entry in `Service` table. The `WHERE` then filters that result set to retain only those employees which do not have a corresponding entry in `Service`, which is equivalent to your `NOT IN` method.

You should understand that there is nothing wrong with using a subquery in this case, but using a join may be preferable for performance reasons. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query) question provides an excellent analysis of joins vs subqueries.

Comment: I believe what you have here (or its equivalent) is in fact what most decent SQL engines will internally convert the OP's original query into.

Comment: Yes, I believe that sort of optimisation is done quite commonly.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Employee e 
WHERE (
      SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM service s 
      WHERE e.EmployeeId = s.EmployeeId
      ) = 0;
```

I do not recommend doing this, though.

Another solution with better performance (from [Conffusion's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057317/alternative-methodology-instead-of-not-in#comment38978319_25057425))

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Employee e 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM service s 
      WHERE e.EmployeeId = s.EmployeeId
      );
```

Comment: or: where not exists (select 1 from service where e.employeeid = s.employeeid). Not exists is faster then count.

Answer (score 0):

didNot tested, but I think it can work:

```
select *
from (select distinct E.*, S.employeeid serviceEmployeeid 
        from employee E left outer join service S on e.employeeid = S.employeeid)
where serviceEmployeeid is null
```

added distinct for the situation a single employee had multiple services.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would produce your solution.

```
SELECT EmployeeId
FROM 
  EMPLOYEE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  SERVICE
  ON (EMPLOYEE.EmployeeId = SERVICE.EmployeeId)
WHERE
  SERVICE.ServiceId IS NULL
;
```